# When using rsync to sync a sparsebundle are --delete and -X for extended attributes options recommended?

Tags: macos, rsync, sparsebundle, extended-attributes

I have scripts that rsync Time Machine sparsebundles to a remote server for offsite backups.  I've always assumed that extended attributes are a function of the internal image filesystem and not the sparsebundle band files themselves, but with Monterey I'm not sure anymore.  I'm also unsure whether Time Machine deletes some band files.  Just in case I changed my scripts to use the --delete option in rsync.  I'm not sure if adding the -X option for extended attributes will give me more problems than it's worth, as I've experienced permission errors in the past with this option.  Does anyone have experience with this?